# What is the recommended way to shim Object.entries in Ember.js?

Tags: internet-explorer, ember.js

Some of my users use Internet Explorer 11 which doesn’t support `Object.entries`. I’d like to still support that browser but I’m using `Object.entries` in multiple places within my codebase.

I see that there’s a shim available. Where would be the best place to place this shim within Ember?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would personally put that into an initializer. I like it there becasue it's discreet and easy to remove later.

`ember generate initializer object-entries-polyfill`

app/initializers/object-entries-polyfill.js

```
export function initialize(application) {
  //from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill
  if (!Object.entries) {
    Object.entries = function( obj ){
    var ownProps = Object.keys( obj ),
        i = ownProps.length,
        resArray = new Array(i); // preallocate the Array
    while (i--)
      resArray[i] = [ownProps[i], obj[ownProps[i]]];

    return resArray;
    };
  }
};

export default {
  initialize
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do following (not sure it works for `Object.entries` but I think it should as it works for other features that IE does not have):

1. In `config/targets.js` add `'ie 11'` to `browsers` array (because by default it is there only for prod env, as far as I can tell)
2. In `ember-cli-build.js` configure ember-cli-babel to include polyfill:

   ```
   let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
     'ember-cli-babel': {
       includePolyfill: true,
     },
   });
   ```